# c# Can I turn EventArgs in to MouseEventArgs?

Tags: c#

I *think* this is to do with casting:

First, I declare an event handler for my picturebox:

```
        pictureBox1.MouseHover += new EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseHover);
```

Next I'm trying to check whether the left mousebutton is held down with:

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            /*some gibberish for when the left mouse button is held*/
        }

    }
```

But this doesn't work, because `EventArgs` is not `MouseEventArgs`

Can I `Cast` or somehow convert `EventArgs e` to be treated as MouseEventArgs so that the above code would work?

Comment: C#7: `if (e is MouseEventArgs me) { if (me.Button == MouseButtons.Left) { } }`. But that only works if `e` *actually is* MouseEventArgs, and in this case it turns out it isn't.

Comment: Can you turn an apple in an orange?

Comment: There's a reason `MouseHover` is not declared as taking a `MouseEventArgs`: it doesn't pass it. There are separate events for mouse clicks (`MouseDown`, `MouseUp`). `Hover` only indicates that hovering is occurring; information about the mouse button state isn't part of the event. You may be looking for `Control.MouseButtons` instead.

Comment: You can use [MouseMove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if a mouse button is pressed while moving the mouse, then you should subscribe to `PictureBox.MouseDown`, `PictureBox.MouseMove` and `PictureBox.MouseUp` events if you want to record the mouse movement from the point you first pressed the button, while you're moving the mouse while still holding the button and when you release the button.

```
private void PictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        //Handle mouse down logic here (press).
    }
}

private void PictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        //Handle mouse move logic here (hold).
    }
}

private void PictureBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        //Handle mouse up logic here (release).
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I accepted this answer since it addresses and fixes my issue - all I needed was to change Hover to Move to get MouseEventArgs instead of EventArgs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating an event handler and you know that you are passing a MouseEventArgs parameter, you can use the following code:

```
MouseEventArgs me = e as MouseEventArgs;
```

If you can't trust the code which invokes the event, you can test e with:

```
if (e.GetType() == typeof(MouseEventArgs))
```

So, the correct answer to "Can I turn EventArgs into MouseEventArgs?" is, "No, if the original event argument did not originate as a MouseEventArg. However, you can pass MouseEventArgs e to an event handler which defines e as an EventArgs type as in:

```
        private void MainMouseDownEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.GetType() == typeof(MouseEventArgs))
            {
                // frmMain correctly passes MouseEventArgs e, but frmDraw does not know it is a MouseEventArgs class
                MouseEventArgs me = e as MouseEventArgs;
                X1 = me.X;
                Y1 = me.Y;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Can you turn an apple in an orange?* No. Well, you can't just make an `MouseEventArgs` from an `EventArgs` instance.

In this case, your code doesn't make sense. You are trying to get the button of a hover event. Hovering is done without any button clicks. If you want to know the button pressed at time of hovering, you need to cache the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events first to register what button was clicked.

Comment: _"Can you turn an apple into orange?"_ [Of course](http://freakonomics.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/new-apple-orange-small-296x300.jpg) ;-)